# Retrieving data using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I've been trying to retrieve some data using BeautifulSoup but I've hit a brick wall.

```
<tr data-name="A Color Similar to Slate">
                <th class="unique"><a href="/item/5052/6/223d382afee2ac6857d3298b800652e0" class="item-link"><span style='color: #7D6D00'>A Color Similar to Slate</span></a></th>
                <td class=unique>0/10</td>
                <td class="unique" data-conversion="14 ref">35,000</td>
                <td class="unique" data-conversion="13.02 ref">32,550</td>
                <td class="unique" data-conversion="13.51 ref">33,775</td>
                <td class="unique" style="text-align: center;"><a class="item-link-backpack" href="http://backpack.tf/stats/Unique/A+Color+Similar+to+Slate/tradable/craftable"><img src="/img/bptf-icon.png" alt="View on Backpack.tf"/></a></td>
            </tr>
```

What I'd like my script to do is to take an input (in this case a "A Color Similar to Slate" string) and have it return the data below(0/10, 14 ref etc) so that I can compare it to a different set of data. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
similar_color = soup.find('tr', {'data-name': 'A Color Similar to Slate'})
for value in similar_color.find_all('td'):
    print(value.text)
```

Should result in:

```
0/10
35,000
```

and so on, so forth.  However, it seems like you want to grab the text value sometimes, and the `data-conversion` value other times.  To do that, you would just substitute the `print(value.text)` line with:

```
print(value.attrs.get('data-conversion'))
```

Comment: no problem! if it helped a bit, please consider checking the green answer button :-)

Answer (score 0):

In case you will use it on other HTML style files:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html= """<tr data-name="A Color Similar to Slate">
                <th class="unique"><a href="/item/5052/6/223d382afee2ac6857d3298b800652e0" class="item-link"><span style='color: #7D6D00'>A Color Similar to Slate</span></a></th>
                <td class=unique>0/10</td>
                <td class="unique" data-conversion="14 ref">35,000</td>
                <td class="unique" data-conversion="13.02 ref">32,550</td>
                <td class="unique" data-conversion="13.51 ref">33,775</td>
                <td class="unique" style="text-align: center;"><a class="item-link-backpack" href="http://backpack.tf/stats/Unique/A+Color+Similar+to+Slate/tradable/craftable"><img src="/img/bptf-icon.png" alt="View on Backpack.tf"/></a></td>
            </tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
texts = [i.get_text() for i in soup.find_all() if i.get_text()]

print(texts[texts.index('A Color Similar to Slate'):])
```

This checks all the tags not just `td`. The output is `['A Color Similar to Slate', 'A Color Similar to Slate', 'A Color Similar to Slate', '0/10', '35,000', '32,550', '33,775']`